# How to support Chinese in http request body?

Tags: web-services, security, http, rest, erlang

```
URL = http://example.com,
Header = [],
Type = "application/json",
Content = "我是中文",

Body = lists:concat(["{\"type\":\"0\",\"result\":[{\"url\":\"test.cn\",\"content\":\"", unicode:characters_to_list(Content), "\"}]}"]),
lager:debug("URL:~p, Body:~p~n", [URL, Body]),
HTTPOptions = [],
Options = [],
Response = httpc:request(post, {URL, Header, Type, Body}, HTTPOptions, Options),
```

The http request body received by http server is not 我是中文。How do I fix this issue?

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596193/erlang-and-binary-with-cyrillic) might help.

Comment: http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Luck of the Encoding

You must take special care to ensure input is what you think it is because it may differ from what you expect.

This answer applies to the Erlang release that I'm running which is **R16B03-1**. I'll try to get all of the details in here so you can test with your own install and verify.

If you don't take specific action to change it, a string will be interpreted as follows:

#### In the Terminal (OS X 10.9.2)

```erlang
TerminalContent = "我是中文",
TerminalContent = [25105,26159,20013,25991].
```

In the terminal the string is interpreted as a list of unicode characters.

#### In a Module

```erlang
BytewiseContent = "我是中文",
BytewiseContent = [230,136,145,230,152,175,228,184,173,230,150,135].
```

In a module, the default encoding is `latin1` and strings containing unicode characters are interpreted `bytewise` lists (of UTF8 bytes).

If you use data encoded like `BytewiseContent`, `unicode:characters_to_list/1` will double-encode the Chinese characters and `ææ¯ä` will be sent to the server where you expected `我是中文`.

### Solution

1. Specify the encoding for each source file and term file.
2. If you run an `erl` command line, ensure it is setup to use unicode.
3. If you read data from files, translate the bytes from the `bytewise` encoding to unicode before processing (this goes for binary data acquired using `httpc:request/N` as well).

If you embed unicode characters in your module, ensure that you indicate as much by commenting within the first two lines of your module:

```erlang
%% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This will change the way the module interprets the string such that:

```erlang
UnicodeContent = "我是中文",
UnicodeContent = [25105,26159,20013,25991].
```

Once you have ensured that you are concatenating characters and not bytes, the concatenation is safe. Don't use `unicode:characters_to_list/1` to convert your string/list until the whole thing has been built up.

#### Example Code

The following function works as expected when given a `Url` and a list of unicode character `Content`:

```erlang
http_post_content(Url, Content) ->
    ContentType = "application/json",
    %% Concat the list of (character) lists
    Body = lists:concat(["{\"content\":\"", Content, "\"}"]),
    %% Explicitly encode to UTF8 before sending
    UnicodeBin = unicode:characters_to_binary(Body),
    httpc:request(post,
        {
            Url,
            [],          % HTTP headers
            ContentType, % content-type
            UnicodeBin   % the body as binary (UTF8)
            },
        [],            % HTTP Options
        [{body_format,binary}] % indicate the body is already binary
        ).
```

To verify results I wrote the following HTTP server using `node.js` and `express`. The sole purpose of this ***dead-simple server*** is to sanity check the problem and solution.

```javascript
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
util = require('util');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('You probably want to perform an HTTP POST');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  util.log("body: "+util.inspect(req.body, false, 99));
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/flitbit/11388074)

#### Verifying

Again in Erlang, the following function will check to ensure that the HTTP response contains the echoed JSON, and ensures the exact unicode characters were returned.

```erlang
verify_response({ok, {{_, 200, _}, _, Response}}, SentContent) ->
    %% use jiffy to decode the JSON response
    {Props} = jiffy:decode(Response),
    %% pull out the "content" property value
    ContentBin = proplists:get_value(<<"content">>, Props),
    %% convert the binary value to unicode characters,
    %% it should equal what we sent.
    case unicode:characters_to_list(ContentBin) of
        SentContent -> ok;
        Other ->
            {error, [
                {expected, SentContent},
                {received, Other}
                ]}
    end;
verify_response(Unexpected, _) ->
    {error, {http_request_failed, Unexpected}}.
```

The complete [`example.erl` module is posted in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/flitbit/11388377).

Once you've got the example module compiled and an echo server running you'll want to run something like this in an Erlang shell:

```erlang
inets:start().

Url = example:url().

Content = example:content().

Response = example:http_post_content(Url, Content).
```

If you've got `jiffy` set up you can also verify the content made the round trip:

```erlang
example:verify_response(Response, Content).
```

You should now be able to confirm round-trip encoding of any unicode content.

### Translating Between Encodings

While I explained the encodings above you will have noticed that `TerminalContent`, `BytewiseContent`, and `UnicodeContent` are all lists of integers. You should endeavor to code in a manner that allows you to be certain what you have in hand.

The oddball encoding is `bytewise` which may turn up when working with modules that are not "unicode aware". [Erlang's guidance on working with unicode](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html) mentions this near the bottom under the heading **Lists of UTF-8 Bytes**. To translate `bytewise` lists use:

```erlang
%% from http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html
utf8_list_to_string(StrangeList) ->
    unicode:characters_to_list(list_to_binary(StrangeList)).
```

---

#### My Setup

As far as I know, I don't have local settings that modify Erlang's behavior. My Erlang is **R16B03-1** built and distributed by [Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp), my machine runs OS X 10.9.2.