# URL argument was malformed URL in corona sdk

Tags: url, coronasdk

If url string of network.request contains Chinese characters in Corona SDK,the console will log "URL argument was malformed URL".For example,if the url string is "[http://xxxx.com?name=张三&age=23](http://xxxx.com?name=%E5%BC%A0%E4%B8%89&age=23)",the problem will occur,but if the Chinese characters are replaced by English characters ,everything will be ok.how can issue be solved?

Comment: Try this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304233/how-to-support-chinese-in-http-request-body-erlang

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the Chinese characters before `GET` or `POST` it.
An example here:

```
local p ="张三"

function urlEncode( str )
    assert( type(str)=='string', "urlEncode: input not a string" )
    if (str) then
        str = string.gsub (str, "\n", "\r\n")
        str = string.gsub (str, "([^%w %-%_%.%~])",
            function (c) return string.format ("%%%02X", string.byte(c)) end)
        str = string.gsub (str, " ", "+")
    end
    return str
end

function urlDecode( str )
    assert( type(str)=='string', "urlDecode: input not a string" )
    str = string.gsub (str, "+", " ")
    str = string.gsub (str, "%%(%x%x)",
        function(h) return string.char(tonumber(h,16)) end)
    str = string.gsub (str, "\r\n", "\n")
    return str
end

network.request("http://xxxx.com/s?w="..urlEncode(p), "GET", function(event)
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        --do something
    end
end)
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304233/how-to-support-chinese-in-http-request-body-erlang