# Spring Controller @RequestMapping does not support for non English special characters

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am currently working on an old spring app which exposes REST API for mobile devices. I need to create a new REST service for a Json request with multiple language support. But when I testing this it only support English. When I try with an other language it gives me ????? characters for relevant data.

following is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "lk.test.com.controller")
public class ControllerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter getMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());
        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

Following is a sample controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "send/push", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public Response sendPush(final @RequestBody CustomerExternalRequest request, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {

        System.out.println(request.getPushMessage());
        Response response = new Response();
        return response;
    }
```

and Relevant Request Object

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class CustomerExternalRequest extends Request{

    private String phoneNo;

    //push send
    private Boolean isOnlyToCurrenltyLoggedDevice;
    private String pushMessage;
    private String pushTitle;
}
```

my Json Request

```
{"request":{"phoneNo":"+94776587745","isOnlyToCurrenltyLoggedDevice":true,"pushMessage":"测试","pushTitle":"测试"}}
```

[And this is my POSTMAN request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocj4F.png)

```
System.out.println(request);
```

prints ?? in the console

Can any one know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: see if this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304233/how-to-support-chinese-in-http-request-body-erlang

Comment: @Hades Thanks for the reply. I think I have missed some configuration in this Spring configurations. I have tried same request with a sample spring boot application and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason and the solution.

When I tried with a spring boot sample app it worked. Because it is has an embedded tomcat server. In my case I used eclipse jetty plugin. I then found a place to change encoding type and changed it to UTF-8 and now it works fine.

[See the configuration screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G610B.png)